# Metrics are not retrieved for APIM Service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I am using Rest API to retrieve the metrics of APIM Service.

I am able to retrieve the metrics for first two days and suddenly I am not able to retrieve them. Are there any restrictions to retrieve the metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Please review the API Documentation. I tried this at my side and it worked for me:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/<ServiceName>/reports/byProduct?$filter=timestamp ge datetime'2019-09-01T00:00:00' and timestamp le datetime'2019-09-15T00:00:00'&api-version=2019-01-01
```

Please pass query parameters as shown in the above URl.

$filter : timestamp ge datetime'2019-09-01T00:00:00' and timestamp le datetime'2019-09-15T00:00:00'

api-version: 2019-01-01